# How do I integrate $\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I integrate $$\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x}$$ ? Tried different ways including the tangent half-angle substitution (which seems to be disastrous).

Comment: No limits of integration? Maybe that would simplify things a lot.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x} \, dx&=
\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x} \, dx+\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x} \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{\sin x}{(1-\cos^2 x)^2 + \cos^4 x} \, dx+\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^4 x + (1-\sin^2 x)^2} \, dx
\end{align}
Now substitute $u_1=\cos x$ for the first term and $u_2=\sin x$ for the second term.

Comment: For the record, WolframAlpha does not return a pretty result: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin+x%2B%5Ccos+x%7D%7B%5Csin%5E4+x+%2B+%5Ccos%5E4+x%7D+%5C%2C+dx